# ¿como agregar JFrame en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

Miren lo que pasa antes usaba netbeans como IDE y viene con el JFrame por defecto, cosa que el Eclipse no, habrá alguna forma de instalarlo o algún plugin similar? **AYUDA**!!!

Edit:

A mí me pasa lo mismo. Hice este proyecto:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Formulario extends JFrame{
private JLabel label1;
public JFrame() {
setLayout(null);
label1=new JLabel("Hola Mundo.");
label1.setBounds(10,20,200,30);
add(label1);
}
public static void main(String[] ar) {
JFrame formulario1=new JFrame();
formulario1.setBounds(10,10,400,300);
formulario1.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

**TODOS** los "*JFrame*" estan subrayados en rojo con el error:

Access restriction: The constructor JLabel(String) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar

> ESTOY DESESPERADO! :C :c :'( :[ :{ D:
> OS PIDO **AYUDA!!!!!!!!!!!**

*Gracias*[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La clase? ya intentaste escribir JFrame y promir ctrl +space para que te la importe en automatico?

Comment: Hola ReKeS.bienvenido al sitio!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no trata de programación.

Comment: Hola Rekes. Te refieres a tener un panel con la interfaz para diseñar tus formularios arrastrando componentes? JFrame usa swing asi que has de importarlo en tu proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cierto, Eclipse no incluye por defecto un GUI Builder como el que si trae el otro IDE, pero existe el plugin [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder), para instalarlo ve a *Help* >> *Install New Software*, si estas usando *Eclipse Neon* pega en la caja de texto *Work with* ésta URL:
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/

Si tienes una version anterior a *Neon* puedes tomar la URL de aquí:
http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Luego de ello seleccionas el checkbox de WindowBuilder y procede con la instalación.

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes de crear tu objeto:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Luego colocar tu puntero de mouse sobre JFrame y en el cuadro desplegable elegir

```
Import 'JFrame' (javax.swing)
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, se agradece tu colaboración pero antes de que publiques  más respuestas te sugiero revises [ask] para que sepas como debe realizarse una correcta pregunta y que debe contener para ser respondida. Es importante revises [answer] para realizar una buena respuesta, saludos.